# Using a low pass filter to calculate average?

Tags: java, filtering, signal-processing, moving-average, lowpass-filter

If I want to calculate an average of 400 data points (noise values from an accelerometer sensor), can I use a low pass function such as this one to do that?

```
private float lowPass(float alpha, float input, float previousOutput) {
    return alpha * previousOutput + (1 - alpha) * input;
}
```

I'm comparing this to simply storing the 400 data points in a `List<float>`, summing them up and dividing by 400.

I'm getting quite different results even with high values for `alpha`. Am I doing something wrong? Can I use the low pass filter to calculate an average, or is it generally better to simply calculate the "real" average?

**EDIT**

My low pass function originally took a `float[]` as input and output, since my data comes from a 3-axis accelerometer. I changed this to `float` and removed the internal `for` loop to avoid confusion. This also means that the input/output is now passed as primitive values, so the method returns a `float` instead of operating directly on the output array.

Comment: what is alpha in your function?

Comment: I mean, that's not a classic averaging operation, isn't it?

Comment: @magicleon that looks like an exponentially weighted moving average.

Answer (score 0):

If you can afford to compute the arithmetic mean (which doesn't even require extra storage if you keep a running sum) then that would probably be the better option in most cases for reasons described bellow.

*Warning: maths ahead*

For sake of comparing the arithmetic average with the first-order recursive low-pass filter you are using, let's start with a signal of `N` samples, where each sample has a value equal to `m` plus some Gaussian noise of variance `v`. Let's further assume that the noise is independent from sample to sample.

The computation of the arithmetic average on this signal will give you a random result with mean `m` and variance `v/N`.

Assuming the first `previousOutput` is initialized to zero, deriving the mean and variance for the last output (`output[N-1]`) of the low-pass filter, we would get a mean `m * (1 - alpha^N)` and variance `v * (1-alpha)^2 * (1-alpha^(2*N)) / (1 - alpha^2)`.
An immediate problem that can be seen is that for large `m`, the estimated mean `m * (1 - alpha^N)` can be quite far for the true value `m`. This problem unfortunately gets worse as `alpha` gets closer to 1. This occurs because the filter does not have time to ramp up to it's steady state value.

To avoid this issue, one may consider initializing the first `previousOutput` with the first input sample.

In this case the mean and variance of the last output would be `m` and `v * ((1-alpha)^2*(1-alpha^(2*N-2))/(1-alpha^2) + alpha^(2*N-2))` respectively. This time the problem is that for larger `alpha` the output variance is largely dominated by the variance of that first sample that was used for the initialization. This is particularly obvious in the following comparative graph of the output variance (normalized by the input variance):

[image]

So, either you get a bias in the estimated mean when initializing `previousOutput` with zero, or you get a large residual variance when initializing with the first sample (much more so than with the arithmetic mean computation).

Note in conclusion that actual performance may vary for your specific data, depending on the nature of the observed variations.

Comment: Thanks, however I think you misunderstood my implementation. The arrays and for loop were simply there because my data comes from a 3-axis accelerometer, so it consists of a `float[3]{ X, Y, Z }`. I have updated the code in the question to make it clearer.

Comment: Ah that makes more sense. The performance analysis and corresponding conclusion should still apply though.

Answer (score -2):

What's `output[]` ? If it holds the results and you initialize with 0s, then this term will always be zero: `alpha * output[i]`

And in general:

> A low-pass filter is a filter that passes signals with a frequency
>   lower than a certain cutoff frequency and attenuates signals with
>   frequencies higher than the cutoff frequency.

So it is not average it is basically a cutoff up to a specific threshold.

Comment: A moving average is just a special case of a low pass filter.

Comment: a low pass filter cuts the high frequences, yeah. It corresponds to an averaging, essentially, because you eliminate the high variation of the signal. An example can be seen in image processing too, where the blurring is an averaging process and it corresponds to a low pass filtering in frequence.

Comment: @magicleon, yes it cuts the high frequencies, but it doesn't cut the lower values, while the average is more like 2 filters combined - a low-pass and a high-pass - to obtain a range near the center (average)

Comment: `output[]` is initialized to the first value of `input[]` before performing the first iteration of filtering. But even it it was to be initialized to `0`, it wouldn't stay at `0`, since `output[]` would be assigned `(1-alpha)*input[i]` on the first filtering iteration... Also, [the page you're quoting](https://www.mathworks.com/discovery/low-pass-filter.html) also states _"Low-pass filters [...] are often used to clean up signals, remove noise, **perform data averaging** [...]"_.

Comment: @ACV - In general, a moving average is **not** a high-pass filter (nor a band-pass filter).